# How to add flex-box to React Rating?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm using [React Rating](https://github.com/dreyescat/react-rating) in my app...

In React I render the Rating component like so:

```
<div className="rate-mod">
  <Rating {...input}
    stop={3}
    empty={['temp 1', 'temp 2', 'temp 3']}
  />
</div>
```

The output looks like:

```
<div class="rate-mod">
  <span name="skill_id_1" value="">
    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;">
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;">
    </span>
  </span>
   ....
</div>
```

How can I make the rate-mod a flex box so each rating option is within the flex box and has a width so that the options fill the full width of the rate-mod?

Comment: Can you attach a working code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `display: flex; flex-direction: column` to `rate-mod`, the items (assumed your *options*), will stack vertical and with `width: 100%` they will have the width of their parent, the `rate-mod`.

```css
.rate-mod {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.rate-mod > span {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate-mod">
  <span name="skill_id_1" value="">
    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    
  </span>

  <span name="skill_id_1" value="">
    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    
  </span>

  <span name="skill_id_1" value="">
    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    
  </span>
</div>
```

---

If you mean that the `span` with the name `"skill_id_1` should be the flex box, you add the flex properties like this (here with them stacked horizontally using `flex-grow`).

```css
.rate-mod > span {
  display: flex;
}
.rate-mod > span > span {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate-mod">
  <span name="skill_id_1" value="">
    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    
    
    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    

    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    
  </span>

  <span name="skill_id_2" value="">
    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    
    
    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    

    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    
  </span>

</div>
```

Instead of the immediate child selector `>`, you can use the attribute selector, `[attr^=value]`, which targets an element with an attribute value which is prefixed by *value*, and in this case all elements with a value starting with `skill_id`.

```css
.rate-mod [name^='skill_id'] {
  display: flex;
}
.rate-mod [name^='skill_id'] > span {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate-mod">
  <span name="skill_id_1" value="">
    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    
    
    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    

    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    
  </span>

  <span name="skill_id_2" value="">
    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    
    
    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    

    <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <span class="temp 1"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span>      
    </span>    
  </span>

</div>
```